# Unable to connect Dynamo via DAX from on premise application

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I am unable to connect Dynamo via DAX. I am getting below exception while connecting to the endpoint, Accesskey/securekey and Proxy are already setup.

com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to call cluster endpoint: No endpoints available

Comment: How is your proxy set up? Getting DAX to work with a proxy is quite tricky due to how the client does endpoint resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the security group that you have attached is open inbound rule for port 8111

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

**Update :** I was trying establish connection with DAX from on premise application running on Tomcat.But its not possible due to security restrictions from Amazon.If you want to use DAX you should always deploy your applications in EC2 instances or via Lambda if it is serverless.

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details there instead of adding the details as an answer.

Comment: This is just an update, not the answer. However question is also changed.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that your ClusterClient is unable to find your DAX hosts, and there is some kind of issue in the network connection.

For a proxy setup, I was able to resolve this by switching from the ClusterClient to a DaxClient, where I could control the endpoint that the client reached out to.